# Как глобально использовать параметр функции из другого файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, импорт

У меня есть один основной файл с данными и второй, где я вызываю функции передавая в них данные из первого файла, но использовать могу только в самих функциях, а вне функции выдает ошибку что данной переменной нету.

**Файл A**:

```
from b import *

f = "Hello World"
d(f)
```

**Файл B**:

```
def d(f):
    print(f) #Hello World

print(f)#Error: переменной не существует(global f - не помогает)
```

Comment: Перепроверьте мой код, я изменил его

Answer (score 0):

Можете сделать так, хотя я всё-равно не понимаю, зачем вам отдельный от функций `print` во втором файле.

**A.py**

```py
f = "Hello World!"
from B import*
d(f)
```

В этом случае переменная `f` будет определена до того, как импортируется файл `B.py` и из него запустится `print(f)`.

Answer (score -1):

Я перепроверил ваш код, и заметил, что у вас стоит две `print`. Один внутри `d` функции и один снаружи функции. Либо удаляете тот, который снаружи, либо делаете новую переменную:

**A.py**

```py
from B import*
f = "Hello World!"
d(f)
```

**B.py**

```py
f = None
def(a):
    global f
    print(a)
    f = a
print(f)
```

Comment: я не могу импортировать из A так как это основной файл который запускается

Comment: Я перепроверил ваш код, работает без проблем

Comment: Сейчас изменю свой ответ